# Асинхронное выполнение кода php (из процесса)

Tags: php, асинхронность

Подскажите как выполнить php-скрипт асинхронно?
Точнее интересует, как запустить скрипта и закрыть соединение с клиентом (не обязательно браузером).
Пробовал компонент Process от symfony, выполнял вот это для примера:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    $lg = Logger::getInstance();
    $lg->log('log', "message ${i}");
}
```

Логгер свой, работает корректно, а вот этот цикл выполняется то 13 то 8 итераций.
Тайм-аут увеличивал (setTimeout), но все равно работает, как описал выше.

В продакшн пойдет еще более долгое выполнение...

Comment: Попробуйте поковыряться [тут](https://github.com/iCubeDm/php-subprocess-example). А вообще, лучше наверно делать это через `cron`. Хотя еще как вариант, сделать асинхронный `POST` или `GET` запрос, с соответствующими заголовками. Или каким-нибудь демоном.

Comment: Можете выносить выполнение в очередь. Например RabbitMQ

Comment: кроны не подходят, а очередь итак уже используется, не хочется дальше все усложнять, нужен какой-то простой способ. Вот просто как пришел запрос, ставим выполняться скрипт и возвращаем ответ, не дожидаясь выполнения.. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: https://reactphp.org/ библиотека асинхронного PHP

Comment: Всем спасибо! вот такое нашел решение (забыл упомянуть все это должно было работать под виндой)                                 
      `pclose(
    popen(
        'powershell.exe "Start-Process C:\server\php\php.exe C:\server\www\signature\testProcess.php -WindowStyle Hidden"',
        'r'
    )
);`